# xbox one controller crashes ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, xbox-one

When I plug in my xbox one controller via USB it crashes my system.
 The entire system locks up shortly after plugging the controller in.  I have to push the power button in order to get a working system.

I should add I am not trying to play a game or anything.  I just want to be able to plug in the device and use libusb on it.

I don't really know what else to say.  I tried every port and I get the same result.  Please let me know if you need more information.

**14.04.3 - 3.19.0-37-generic**

**UPDATE : installed new kernel still same error
4.2.0-19-generic from repos**

syslog, after several tries and my computer locking up I got this.

```
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.184051] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.313756] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=02dd
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.313763] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.313767] usb 1-2: Product: Controller
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.313770] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Microsoft
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.313773] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 7EED8F0492D3
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 6: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2"
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 6 was not an MTP device
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.328279] input: Generic X-Box pad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/input/input21
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.328486] BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 000000000000004e
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.328523] IP: [<ffffffffc09ac3d8>] xpad_probe+0x358/0xa10 [xpad]
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.328551] PGD 3cc68b067 PUD 3d0dca067 PMD 0 
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.328576] Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP 
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.328592] Modules linked in: xpad(+) ff_memless hidp aufs ctr ccm bbswitch(OE) ebtable_nat ebtables xt_CHECKSUM iptable_mangle ipt_MASQUERADE nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4 iptable_nat nf_nat_ipv4 bridge stp llc rfcomm bnep ip6t_REJECT nf_reject_ipv6 nf_log_ipv6 xt_hl ip6t_rt nf_conntrack_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv6 ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 nf_log_ipv4 nf_log_common xt_LOG xt_limit xt_tcpudp binfmt_misc xt_addrtype nls_iso8859_1 arc4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 xt_conntrack ip6table_filter snd_hda_codec_realtek ip6_tables snd_hda_codec_generic intel_rapl nf_conntrack_netbios_ns nf_conntrack_broadcast iosf_mbi nf_nat_ftp nvidia(POE) nf_nat x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp nf_conntrack_ftp coretemp nf_conntrack kvm_intel iptable_filter kvm ip_tables x_tables snd_soc_rt5640 crct10dif_pclmul snd_soc_rl6231 crc32_pclmul snd_hda_intel iwlmvm snd_soc_core snd_hda_controller snd_hda_codec snd_compress mxm_wmi ghash_clmulni_intel snd_pcm_dmaengine mac80211 snd_hwdep aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw snd_pcm i915 gf128mul uvcvideo glue_helper ablk_helper videobuf2_vmalloc snd_seq_midi cryptd videobuf2_memops snd_seq_midi_event videobuf2_core snd_rawmidi v4l2_common joydev iwlwifi snd_seq videodev hid_multitouch btusb media snd_seq_device serio_raw bluetooth snd_timer drm_kms_helper cfg80211 drm snd ie31200_edac mei_me mei shpchp i2c_algo_bit lpc_ich edac_core soundcore i2c_hid wmi i2c_designware_platform mac_hid soc_button_array dw_dmac snd_soc_sst_acpi 8250_dw i2c_designware_core spi_pxa2xx_platform dw_dmac_core video parport_pc ppdev lp parport hid_generic usbhid hid psmouse ahci libahci sdhci_acpi sdhci
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.329303] CPU: 7 PID: 4315 Comm: systemd-udevd Tainted: P           OE  3.19.0-37-generic #42~14.04.1-Ubuntu
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.329339] Hardware name: Razer Blade/RAZER            , BIOS 3.15 12/22/2014
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.329372] task: ffff8803fb499d70 ti: ffff8803d73c4000 task.ti: ffff8803d73c4000
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.329399] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffffc09ac3d8>]  [<ffffffffc09ac3d8>] xpad_probe+0x358/0xa10 [xpad]
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.329433] RSP: 0018:ffff8803d73c7b48  EFLAGS: 00010206
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.329452] RAX: ffff88041977d600 RBX: ffff88041987fc00 RCX: ffff8803fb57d800
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.329477] RDX: 0000000000000048 RSI: 0000000000000008 RDI: ffff88041977d6c0
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.329516] RBP: ffff8803d73c7b98 R08: ffff8803d5c01060 R09: ffff88041f003800
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.329661] R10: ffffffff815ab80e R11: ffff88041f000d50 R12: ffff8803f0546d00
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.329704] R13: ffff8803fb57d890 R14: 0000000000000001 R15: ffff88041a039000
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.329733] FS:  00007f245d8c4880(0000) GS:ffff88042fbc0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.329763] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.329784] CR2: 000000000000004e CR3: 000000041aeb1000 CR4: 00000000001407e0
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.329810] Stack:
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.329818]  ffff8803d73c7b98 ffffffff81500c42 ffff8803f0546d90 ffff8803fb57d800
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.329849]  ffff880419adec00 ffff8803fb57d890 ffff8803fb57d800 ffffffffc09af088
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.329879]  ffff88041987fc30 ffffffffc09af1c0 ffff8803d73c7be8 ffffffff815b10eb
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.329910] Call Trace:
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.329924]  [<ffffffff81500c42>] ? __pm_runtime_set_status+0x132/0x210
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.329951]  [<ffffffff815b10eb>] usb_probe_interface+0x1bb/0x300
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.329977]  [<ffffffff814f5875>] driver_probe_device+0x155/0x400
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.330000]  [<ffffffff814f5bfb>] __driver_attach+0x9b/0xa0
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.330023]  [<ffffffff814f5b60>] ? __device_attach+0x40/0x40
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.330046]  [<ffffffff814f3733>] bus_for_each_dev+0x63/0xa0
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.330068]  [<ffffffff814f520e>] driver_attach+0x1e/0x20
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.330089]  [<ffffffff814f4e00>] bus_add_driver+0x180/0x240
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.330111]  [<ffffffff814f63e4>] driver_register+0x64/0xf0
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.330133]  [<ffffffff815af8b2>] usb_register_driver+0x82/0x160
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.330160]  [<ffffffffc09b2000>] ? 0xffffffffc09b2000
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.330181]  [<ffffffffc09b201e>] xpad_driver_init+0x1e/0x1000 [xpad]
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.330206]  [<ffffffff81002144>] do_one_initcall+0xd4/0x210
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.330231]  [<ffffffff811cf489>] ? kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0x199/0x220
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.330257]  [<ffffffff810f7d8c>] ? load_module+0x164c/0x1cc0
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.330280]  [<ffffffff810f7dc5>] load_module+0x1685/0x1cc0
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.330301]  [<ffffffff810f3670>] ? store_uevent+0x40/0x40
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.330323]  [<ffffffff810f8576>] SyS_finit_module+0x86/0xb0
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.330347]  [<ffffffff817b738d>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.330368] Code: bc 24 d4 00 00 00 03 48 8b 4b 08 4d 8b 44 24 50 48 8b 49 18 0f 95 c2 48 8d 34 d5 00 00 00 00 48 01 f2 48 8d 14 d1 49 8b 4c 24 08 <0f> b6 7a 06 0f b6 52 02 8b 31 48 89 48 48 4c 89 40 68 c7 80 88 
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.330507] RIP  [<ffffffffc09ac3d8>] xpad_probe+0x358/0xa10 [xpad]
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.330532]  RSP <ffff8803d73c7b48>
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.330545] CR2: 000000000000004e
Dec  2 11:24:13 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1753.350504] ---[ end trace ecd539a79e93e9af ]---
Dec  2 11:24:35 goddard-blade kernel: [ 1775.613045] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 6
```

Comment: "more"? You do not supply *any* information. Not even an error notice or parts of a core dump. Not a thing to go on. " I just want to be able to plug in the device and use libusb on it."  "I should add I am not trying to play a game or anything." So get grid of the need to do want to do that ....

Comment: You know usually it's better to suggest the ways to get information rather then what ever your comment was.  Clearly if I knew a way to add more info I would have.

Comment: That would assume you provided any. Start by adding the actual error message you get.

Comment: I get no error.  The entire system locks up.

Comment: Apparently v1 controllers without the 3.5mm audio still work https://m.reddit.com/r/RetroPie/comments/3wmgso/kernel_panic_when_i_plug_in_an_xbox_one_controller/

Comment: I have a theory that microsoft released an update for the xbox one controller firmware that broke linux compatibility.. I hope that's not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding that Lkml Posting it should work with the original 14.04 3.13 kernel?
https://lkml.org/lkml/2015/11/11/395

**Edit:**
actually that is kind of bad for your Controller. The patch that should have made the kernel working with your Controller made xpad crash the whole kernel: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1514505/comments/37

i would say mark yourself as affected on that ubuntu bug and try to follow it if there is any updates.

http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-input/msg42342.html (from the same guy, he seems quite active to poke the people to get that working) says there was a patch for latest kernels but it is in the half state now: doesnt crash anymore but still doesnt work.